# Can a small, simple and portable (button cell powered) RF transmitter be made to send a pulsed or constant 550-1000 kHz signal?

Tags: rf, transmitter

I'm trying to make a beacon to use with my fishing sonar. It would be attached to the leader of my bait to more easily track its depth and location. A small transmitter and a button cell battery, made properly water-tight, would seem an effective way to provide a signal that would be detected by the sonar transducer (530-1100 kHz). It should be a very easy premise to test.

My concerns are the ability of the signal to travel an effective distance underwater (50-100 ft), and how to configure a transmitter, like [this one](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/TSH512.pdf), to send a constant or pulsed signal.

Comment: Even if you could, I don't think it will last very long. Maybe a minute.

Comment: It's really not clear what the chip would have to do with that?

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks but wondering if a pulse at every 3-5 seconds might preserve battery...just like a beacon.

Comment: @MarcusMüller if you can imagine any type of small transmitter/battery combination I would be interested in trying it.

Comment: A sonar detects sound waves, not radio waves. Also, fish finder sonars operate at 50 - 250 kHz. If you ask about a device that emits sound "pings" in the 50-250 kHz range, maybe some will have ideas.

Comment: @DanielVanAntwerp literally any microcontroller could be used connected to some kind of water-wave-impedance-matched speaker

Comment: @MarkLeavitt How Does Garmin Livescope Work?
Garmin Livescope systems emit a range of frequencies from 530 to 1100 Khz, in a fast rapid-fire motion. This allows targets to be seen in real-time, which translates into a live-action picture on your display.

By emitting both low-frequency and high-frequency signals simultaneously, Garmin lives cope can identify an object (like a fish), as well as track its motion or movement.

Comment: @DanielVanAntwerp that's an active sonar, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar#Active_sonar , probably one with multiple hydrophones allowing for some kind of digital beamforming.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt I like your description of a device that emits sound pings and hope someone has an idea. I would assume this would need to be in the 530-1100kHz range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conceptual problem: You can only sense what the transponder emitted, but you don't know *when* it emitted that. Because you don't know how long things traveled, you can't know how far it traveled, and thus can't get any information about how deep it is.

You need to have at least two, significantly separated (as in: multiple wavelengths) receivers to beamform to get an angle on a 2D plane, and a third one to get the angle in 3D space, and a fourth one to actually locate. (You might be getting around the fourth one if you exploit the *dispersion* of wideband signals, but the math gets very gnarly, and you need to model water temperature and salinity, so I'll go with a "uuuuuh, maybe in your second model?").

Well, that being said: Sure, you can build something like that! Get your quad-channel receiver ready (which basically means: attach your four hydrophones to amplifiers and synchronous ADCs; think of a quad-channel sound card that samples not at 48 kHz, but at 2 MHz). **This sounds like a fun project!** It involves quite a few fields:

- designing watertight enclosures with transducer out-coupling,
- power supply,
- integration of a microcontroller,

  - microcontroller firmware development including
  - control of a PWM unit, probably through DMA
  - "dry-dock" testing of said firmware over the air
- hydrophone array design
- digitizer design or integration of a commercial DAQ
- signal processing software implementation and optimization

So, how far you can reach depends only on

1. how much power you have at your transmitter
2. how much power your noise has in your received signal
3. how much your power drops with distance and
4. for how long it is possible to collect power to increase the effective SNR.

Also:

5. Your ability to locate something depends on the bandwidth of the localization and the effective SNR

So:

1. A coin cell severely limits your possible output power – coin cells rarely do more than 10 mW. You can calculate yourself how long a 20 mAh 3V coin battery would do that, even under perfect conditions.
2. Noise is a real problem in sonar; sadly, I don't have any numbers the noise you'd expect there. It would be wise to assume that in a fishing scenario, you'd have both wideband noise (such as noise from water streaming by your microphone, ground obstacles) and narrowband (as emitted by any periodic mechanical thing on the naval vessel, especially the screw)
3. The square law of attenuation over distance holds for sonar, but is overlaid with higher-order effects, especially on frequencies above 100 kHz.
4. This is a design parameter! I wager you don't need to localize more than once every 20 s. That can give you a very necessary *processing gain*.
5. a continuous wave has zero bandwidth, and hence is pretty much useless for localization; it repeats simply every 1/frequency, making any triangulation impossible.

Looking at these points, I'd say

- a coin cell seems to be the wrong choice, *especially* since you're under water, and weight is probably of much less a concern. However, designing something where you put in a battery that needs to be exchange every hour or so and still needs to be watertight is a terrible challenge. Instead, I'd recommend you consider a larger secondary lithium battery and a wireless charging coil.
- having the power budget a larger lithium battery brings, you could actually use pretty standard hydrophonic transducers.  (think: speaker that has shape to, as good as possible, match the impedance of water, instead of that of air like your Hifi speaker at home)
- As said, you want to emit a wideband signal to allow for unambiguous localization.
- However, true white noise is undesirable: your receivers need to actually fish out (huh, a pun!) that signal from the ambient noise.
- A microcontroller running a simple pseudo-random generator to produce a maybe 10 kS/s stream of binary values would make for a receiver-reproducible reference signal that can easily be transmitted: Use your PWM unit to produce a carrier (e.g. 530 kHz, 1 MHz), and modulate its phase by inverting the output for a 1, or use it straightforward for a 0.
- Receive with your four boat-mounted hydrophones, apply classical time-difference of arrival (TDOA) processing on your laptop. Use the same PRNG to generate the sequence you're correlating against.

The last point is actually pretty involved, because TDOA (and also just beamforming algorithms) for acoustics are harder for acoustics (sonar) than for radio (radar), as the bandwidths relative to the carrier frequency typically are larger and often, nonlinear effects cannot be neglected. But: I believe for fishing depths, and especially if you can make your hydrophone array's baseline large enough, this might be doable.

Comment: I thank you for this amazing response. The Garmin Livescope does a fair job of "seeing" the retrieval of a bait in real time. My flawed concept was that it would see something better while generating its own sound wave and know where it was. I see now that it is essential that it send and receive its signal in order to perform location.  A signal generator on its own would only create background noise. Thank you again for sharing your extensive knowledge!